# Why does my RESTful API return 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http-status-code-404

I am building a REST API in Rails, and am having trouble explaining the observed behaviour of the following piece of code:

```
  #GET /:id/user
  def find_user
    if params.has_key?(:id)
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      if @user.present?
        respond_to do |format|
          response = {:status => "200",
                      :message => "Successfully found user.",
                      :first_name => @user.first_name,
                      :last_name => @user.last_name}

          format.json { render json: response, status: :ok }
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          response = {:status => "422", :message => "Failed to get user."}
          format.json { render json: response, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        response = {:status => "422", :message => "Failed to get user."}
        format.json { render json: response, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

This method represents an API end-point, something that could be accessed via the following URL `http://localhost:3000/api/52/user`.

This seems to work, and when a user with a valid ID is requested, the API responds correctly.

The problem comes when a user with a non-valid ID is requested, i.e.`http://localhost:3000/api/NotAnId/user`).

I have it set up in my method that if a user object is searched for and nothing is found `422 unprocessable entity` is returned as the status code but for some reason it always returns a 404 instead.  Why is it that everytime a user is searched for with an invalid user ID, 404 is returned and not 422? Why is my code being overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `User.find(params[:id]`) raise RecordNotFound if no record can be found, if you change it for `User.find_by_id(params[:id])` it will work as you expected

In fact you can clean the code using only one if

```
#GET /:id/user
def find_user
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @user
    response = {:status => "200",
      :message => "Successfully found user.",
      :first_name => @user.first_name,
      :last_name => @user.last_name
    }
    render json: response, status: :ok 
  else
    response = {:status => "422", :message => "Failed to get user."}
    render json: response, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```